# Lock specific parts of your game before user purchases

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm close to finishing my first iOS app, which is an app containing different card games and text-based games. I'm planning to make it free, but want some of the games to be unavailable until you purchase the premium version. All the games have their separate storyboards and viewcontrollers. Are there any easy ways to implement this method without subscribing to the developer program just yet? I know I won't be able to test the in-app purchase, but what I'm looking for is a way to lock the premium-games.

Comment: Why don't you just do it, for a start, with a specific target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible given that you have a way of tracking whether the user has purchased or not.

For example,

1. Store the user's premium status (preStatus) as "true" or false"
2. Create a boolean logic that checks for user's premium status before allowing usage

So if a user needs to tap a button to go to a premium game, you can code as follows:

```
if preStatus == true {

//segue to premium game

} else {

//alert message "requires premium status"

}
```

This if-statement would be placed where you specify segue in

> button.addTarget

Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I understand! Thanks :)